# How to get mouse position?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript

This is my [demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/BVnWWWob2A2gQHumyTkq/src/app.html?p=stories) (studio.webcomponents)

When I hover over the first row, the div should line up with the mouse position.

**Note:** Need to consider scrollbars

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<template>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered">
        <thead>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Company English Name</th>
            <th>Website</th>
            <th>License Type</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th>Update Date</th>
            <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: none;">
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="1">
                    1
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="2">
                    2
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="3">
                    3
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="4">
                    4
                </td>
                <td onmouseover={mouseOver} onmouseout={mouseOut} data-id="5">
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox-button" label="select" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div if:true={showDiv} class="slds-popover slds-nubbin_left slds-box" style={boxStyle}>
        ttttttttttttttttttt ?!@
    </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement,track } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  boxStyle = 'position:absolute;';
  showDiv = false;
  mouseOver (event) {
      let x = '';
      let y = '';
      if(event.PageX || event.PageY){
        x = event.PageX;
        y = event.PageY;
      }else if (event.clientX || event.clientY){
        x = event.clientX;
        y = event.clientY;
      }
      this.showDiv = true;
      this.boxStyle += 'top:' + y + 'px; left:' + x  + 'px';
      console.log('boxStyle => ' + this.boxStyle);
    }

  mouseOut (evt) {
    this.showDiv = false;
    // var dataId = evt.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    // console.log('dataId 222=> ' + dataId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems. `PageX` and `PageY` should be `pageX` and `pageY`. JavaScript is case-sensitive. Further, we typically put hovers next to an element, not right on the mouse cursor. This causes flickering and an unprofessional-looking UX. Finally, you're growing an infinitely long list of CSS positions. This will eventually use too much memory, or cause the rendering to slow down.

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
  mouseOver(event) {
    const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const y = rect.top + window.scrollY;
    const x = rect.right + window.scrollX;
    this.showDiv = true;
    this.boxStyle = `position: absolute; top: ${y}px; left: ${x}px`;
  }
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/z2NRLQBbXsXze1LwLP3J/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: Thank you very much  ^^